# string to array in java

Tags: multidimensional-array

i have this arraylist and i want to put the data in array.but i have the problem to separate the data.
ArrayList data_list:

```
g e r m a n y
a u s t r a l i a
n e w z e a l a n d
e n g l a n d
c o s t a r i c a
p h i l i p i n a
m y a n m a r
t h a i l a n d
```

note:each of letter is separate by space.
i want to separate the name of the country to into separate letter such as
germany becomes g e r m a n y
i plan to convert the arraylist to 2d array.so the output become like this:
String[][] country;

```
country[0][0]=g
country[0][1]=e
country[0][2]=r
country[0][3]=m
country[0][4]=a
country[0][5]=n
country[0][6]=y

country[1][0]=a
country[1][1]=u
country[1][2]=s
country[1][3]=t
country[1][4]=r
country[1][5]=a
country[1][6]=l
country[1][7]=i
country[1][8]=a
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Is our original ArrayList an array list of String ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ArrayList looks like this:

```
List<String> countries = Arrays.asList("g e r m a n y", "a u s t r a l i a", "n e w z e a l a n d",
    "e n g l a n d", "c o s t a r i c a", "p h i l i p i n a", "m y a n m a r", "t h a i l a n d");
```

Then you can create your array of characters this way:

```
String[][] countryLetters = new String[countries.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
    String country = countries.get(i);
    countryLetters[i] = country.split(" ");
}
// test output
for (String[] c : countryLetters) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

The test output is

```
[g, e, r, m, a, n, y]
[a, u, s, t, r, a, l, i, a]
[n, e, w, z, e, a, l, a, n, d]
[e, n, g, l, a, n, d]
[c, o, s, t, a, r, i, c, a]
[p, h, i, l, i, p, i, n, a]
[m, y, a, n, m, a, r]
[t, h, a, i, l, a, n, d]
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: What code do you run actually? The above code alone runs without problems! (e.g. inside of a test method or static main method)

Answer (score 1):

Use toCharArray() method of String class.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> orig = new ArrayList<String>();
orig.add("G e r m a n y");
orig.add("A u s t r a l i a");

String[][] newArray = new String[orig.size()][];
int i = 0;
for(String s : orig)
    newArray[i++] = s.split(" ");
```

Comment: If you *need* the index in the loop, I usually avoid for-each loops. (Among other things, it limits the scope of the "temporary" variable.)

Comment: This solution doesn't handle the spaces between the letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String a = "germany";
    String b = "india";
    char[] ar = a.toCharArray();
    char[] br = b.toCharArray();
    char [][] td = new char[2][2];
    td[0] = ar;
    td[1] = br;
    System.out.println(td);
    System.out.println(td[0][0]+""+td[0][1]+""+td[0][2]+""+td[0][3]+""+td[0][4]+""+td[0][5]+""+td[0][6]);
```

Comment: what is this?i dont understand